# How to setup Automatic replies date and body?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Is there any way to access and change Automatic replies "out of office" details by code from VSTO objects ?

Need to enable/disable + Change dates and body text

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That can only be done using EWS - use `SetUserOofSettingsRequest` request: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581265(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: can i call the EWS from vsto code ? i don't have server url, username and password to connect there, just need to change the current mailbox oof details

Comment: You can retrieve EWS url from the autodiscover XML (Namespace.AutoDiscoverXml), but there is no API to retrieve the credentials from Outlook.